# i found Null pointer exception while executing testng in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, exception

```
package com.tng;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void SetUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\HARI\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test
    public void googleTitleTest(){
        String title= driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown()
    { 
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest tearDown
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tng.GoogleTest.tearDown(GoogleTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:64)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:364)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:318)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:620)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:850)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1214)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1136)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1066)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1034)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

FAILED: googleTitleTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tng.GoogleTest.googleTitleTest(GoogleTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:821)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:588)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1214)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1136)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1066)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1034)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an object in java the default value it gets is null.

So you declared a class variable driver and hence it gets the value null.

Now in the googletitle method you declared another object driver . So this driver becomes local to that method and what ever you will have scope local.  The class variable driver will still be empty

And in tear down you are accessing the class variable which is still null. That's why you are getting null point exception.

So change

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

To

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

This ensures you are using class variable driver inside the @test method

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line and this will work as PDHide said:

The class variable is denoting as null

```
WebDriver driver;
```

This is the reason for NullPointerException

So, Change the setup method's way of instantiating the driver,

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```